# Running python script from console

Tags: python, console

Totally new to python, and i want to do the following:

I have this code:

```
def assem(myFile):
print "Hello ,World!" 
import myParser
from myParser import Parser
import code
import symboleTable
from symboleTable import SymboleTable


newFile = "Prog.hack"
output = open(newFile, 'w')
input = open(myFile, 'r')


prsr=Parser(input)
while prsr.hasMoreCommands():
    str = "BLANK"
    if(parser.commandType() == Parser.C_COMMAND):
        str="111"+code.comp(prsr.comp())+code.dest(prsr.dest())+code.jump(prsr.jump())+"\n"

    output.write(str)
    prsr.advance()
```

checked the indentation, its ok,its a bit messy over here.

this program needs to run from console and receive a file named `Add.asm`

what is the console command to make it run?

tried :

```
  python assembler.py Add.asm
```

did not work.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

optparse is indeed what you will need for more advanced cl options. However, you could `python assembler.py <filename>` with a simple `if __name__ == "__main__"` block. In lieu of `argparse` or `optparse`, you can use `sys.argv[1]` for a single simple argument to the script.

```
def assem(myFile):
    print "Hello ,World!" 
    import myParser
    from myParser import Parser
    import code
    import symboleTable
    from symboleTable import SymboleTable

    newFile = "Prog.hack"
    output = open(newFile, 'w')
    input = open(myFile, 'r')
    prsr = Parser(input)

    while prsr.hasMoreCommands():
        str = "BLANK"
        if(parser.commandType() == Parser.C_COMMAND):
            str= "111" + code.comp(prsr.comp()
                ) + code.dest(prsr.dest()) + code.jump(prsr.jump()
                ) + "\n"

        output.write(str)
        prsr.advance()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    assem(sys.argv[1])
```

You'll also want to google `python string formatting` and find links like http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: so what should i write to the console?

Comment: and if i dont know the name of the file? any solution?

Comment: i tried this:
if __name__ == '__main__':
 assem(sys.argv[1])
and it worked.
can you edit your answer so that ill choose it?

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for: http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html